# How to set the position of Spinner based on TextView one of values of Array String

Tags: kotlin, position, spinner

I have a spinner set for selecting one of any value set in String array

```
 <string-array name="Address">
        <item>Country</item>
        <item>State</item>
        <item>Area</item>
   </string-array>
```

Based on a selection of spinner positions, I save its value in TextView ( tv_value )

But I don't know when in a scenario where I need to edit these values,
How do I set the position of spinner based on already value in TectView element ( tv_value )

Pl. try to give solution in Kotlin anybody

Answer (score 0):

```
mySpinner.setSelection(arrayAdapter.getPosition(tv_value.text))
```